# Import MongoDB data into Hive Error: Splitter implementation is incompatible

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to import mongodb data into hive.

The jar versions that i have used are

```
ADD JAR /root/HDL/mongo-java-driver-3.4.2.jar;
ADD JAR /root/HDL/mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.2.jar;
ADD JAR /root/HDL/mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar;
```

And my cluster versions are

**Ambari - Version 2.6.0.0, HDFS    2.7.3, Hive 1.2.1000, HBase 1.1.2, Tez  0.7.0
MongoDB Server version:- 3.6.5**

Hive Script:-

```
CREATE TABLE sampletable
( ID STRING,
EmpID STRING,
BeginDate DATE,
EndDate DATE,
Time TIMESTAMP,
Type STRING,
Location STRING,
Terminal STRING)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"ID":"_id","EmpID":"emp_id","BeginDate":"begin_date","EndDate":"end_date","Time":"time","Type":"time_event_type","Location":"location","Terminal":"terminal"}')
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://username:password@10.10.170.43:27017/testdb.testtable');
```

Output:-

hive> select * from sampletable;

OK

**Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Failed to aggregate sample documents. Note that this Splitter implementation is incompatible with MongoDB versions prior to 3.2.**

Please suggest me how can i solve this.

Thanks,

Mohan V

Answer (score 0):

```
set mongo.input.split_size=50;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?